# SQL Server, split column values for every 10 characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Need to split the column Reference values for every 10 characters and need to show it for every row ID

I have data like this

```
ID       Reference
1        405123  ap41502   ag067156
2        a450912   d109456
3        4a4122   g567412  ol09123  pl212671 et61789
4        6t3450   41234a3   01a459014
```

Required Result:

```
ID  Reference
1   405123  ap
1   41502   ag
1   067156
2   a450912   
2   d109456
3   4a4122   g
3   567412  ol
3   09123  pl2
3   12671 et61
3   789
4   6t3450   4
4   1234a3   0
4   1a459014
```

Comment: How about using simple for loop

Comment: I dont know about that but I think we can do with CTE. But I am not able to put it in code

Comment: If you dont know about for-loop, how about try to learn how to write a simple program ? Beginners guide to C#

Comment: I didnt mean I dont know for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use a number / tally table. CROSS JOIN your table to the number table

```
select  *, substring(t.Reference, (n.n * 10) + 1, 10)
from    yourtable t
    cross join numbers n
where   n.n >= 0
and     n.n < ceiling(len(t.Reference) / 10.0)
order by ID, n.n
```

Note : the tally table should contains a line with 0

Comment: This would need to be adjusted to get the first 10 characters, right? It looks like it will start at char index 11. Unless 0 is in the tally table.

Comment: the tally table should contains a line with 0. Note the where clause `n.n >= 0`